# Use localStorage to autocomplete multiple forms on one page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, local-storage, contact-form-7

I have tried manipulating the code used by [Ke Yang](http://wptutorial.narrativecard.com/contact-form-7/) where localStorage is used to mirror text in form fields across to other fields. I want to do something similar.

I have one page (a library of downloadables) which contains about 10 lead-generation forms on it. Once filled out and submitted, the form sends the user the downloadable. Simple stuff. But say the user wants to download more than one thing on this page, it doesn't make sense to have them keep filling out the same forms. The forms are exactly the same, same fields and field-names, just different form IDs.

I want to use localStorage so that once a user has filled out one form on the page, they can check a box at the top of any of the other forms and the browser will autofill their data, then they hit submit. Ideally, this data is saved even after they leave the page. Data submission is handled by the form itself, so there's no need for cookies (and localStorage is better).

Here's the (minimalised) code I have so far, which goes under the **(function($) {** in my scripts.js file:

```
$( ‘input[name=target]’ ).click(function() {if($(‘input[name=target]’).is(‘:checked’)) {
if (localStorage[“first-name”]) {
$(‘input[name=first-name]’).val(localStorage[“first-name”]);
}
if (localStorage[“last-name”]) {
$(‘input[name=last-name]’).val(localStorage[“last-name”]);
}
if (localStorage[“your-email”]) {
$(‘input[name=your-email]’).val(localStorage[“your-email”]);
}
}
});$(‘.wpcf7-text’).change(function () {
localStorage[$(this).attr(‘name’)] = $(this).val();
});
```

Above you see the names of the different fields within one form. The HTML looks like this, where the checkbox would need to be ticked to call the stored form data:

```
<p><input id="target2" name="target2" type="checkbox" value="Downloaded our stuff before?" /> Downloaded our stuff before?</p>
<input type = "text" name ="first-name" class="wpcf7-text">
<input type = "text" name ="last-name" class="wpcf7-text">
<input type = "text" name ="your-email" class="wpcf7-text">
```

The text previously entered into a form will need to be stored (not cleared) *after* a user hits submit, allowing them to download more stuff easily after their first download.

Thanks heaps in advance!

Comment: after checking for isChecked at form submission you should be setting the right parameters to the local storage [try localstorage.setItem()] and at the form load you should be checking to see if data exists in the local storage and set the value of each input box reading the values using localstorage.getItem() or as you did and setting the value to the inputbox

Comment: Hi, please see here on how to post a minimal, complete, and verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that there are too many issues in your code

1) `$( ‘input[name=target]’ )` . This should be $("input[name='target']") .[Check](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) this link for more.

2) Use `setItem` to set the items

3) You need to use `.on` to delegate the change

I have to rewrite the html to make this work. Just for demo I used only three input field

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

<p><input id="target" name="target" type="checkbox" value="Downloaded our stuff before?" /> Downloaded our stuff before?</p>
<input type = "text" name ="first-name" class="wpcf7-text">
<input type = "text" name ="last-name" class="wpcf7-text">
<input type = "text" name ="your-email" class="wpcf7-text">

<script>
  $("#target").change(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        if (localStorage['first-name']) {
$("input[name='first-name']").val(localStorage['first-name']);
}
if (localStorage['last-name']) {
$("input[name='last-name']").val(localStorage['last-name']);
}
if (localStorage['your-email']) {
$("input[name='your-email']").val(localStorage['your-email']);
}
}
});
$(".wpcf7-text").on("change",function () {
localStorage.setItem($(this).attr("name") , $(this).val());
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks so much! To apply this to multiple forms with different checkboxes I've added them in the first line of script and it works perfectly. Thanks again!
`$("#target,#target2,#target3").change(function(){`

Answer (score 0):

Before applying below solution make sure you have given id to your form and your all form controls will have name and id, name and id of control should be identical.

call bellow function before submmiting form

```
function beforeSubmmit(){
    localStorage["YourFormID"]  = JSON.stringify($('#YourFormID').serializeArray());
}
```

on load of page call bellow function

```
function onLoad(){
    if (loadFromLocal == true){
        var fromFileds = JSON.parse(localStorage["YourFormID"])
        for(var formfiled in fromFileds)
        {
            $("#"+formfiled.name).val(formfiled.value);
        }
    }
}
```

and one more thing

```
  $('#YourFormID').serializeArray()
```

this function returns array objects , and each object is having two keys  name & value, name is name of form control and value contains value of the control.

Just store this array in local storage and retrieve on load and set if by for loop, no need to do hard coding.

```
$("form").length
```

this will give you total forms count

```
$("form")[0].id
```

and this will give you id of form,  you can put for loop and store all forms in local storage